# How come whenever I configure/Format Drive on my Xbox 360, it wont show up in horizon or windows explorer?

Tags: xbox-360

[image: Windows explorer says this[![Horizon Says this]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Btxuu.png)

---

First, I configured my flash drive on my xbox 360, Next plugged it up to my computer(Running Windows 10).Then I opened the program Horizon and my USB wouldn't show up. It turned out that windows itself couldn't even get access to the disk. I made sure i ran horizon as an Administrator, but it still wont show my flash drive!

Comment: Possibly because the 360 uses an exFAT format, and maybe Windows doesn't read it?

Comment: @Kaizerwolf No. Horizon has the software to read it, and windows should recognize it through the hardware. I'm thinking it's a port or drive issue.

Comment: nvm I found out the answer. For reason if I format the drive using the allocation size of 8192 on Fat32, whenever I configure it in may xbox afterwards and plug it back into my pc THEN IT  WORKS.